# Tag events rule AWS - Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Cloudformation doesn't support tags for event rules, and I heard somewhere that there's a workaround using cloud formation stacks but I haven't been able to find how exactly.

I know I could use AWS CLI, or tag the resource manually after it's created but I would like to know if there is a workaround using CloudFormation only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) using AWS CloudFormation.

Here’s a [blog post](https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/cloudformation-custom-resources/) describing the process and a [GitHub project](https://github.com/binxio/cfn-tag-provider) that you might want to look into for examples.